# Markov switching model, R package, how to view source code

Tags: r, open-source

I am trying to look into the source code of an implementation of a general Markov switching model, in the MSwM package. I'm new to R, and I already have managed to look into the function msmFit().

However there is another function inside msmFit(), at the bottom called em(). I have not yet been able to view the source code of this inside function. Does anyone know how to view this em()-function?

Many thanks

#### Code and output

```
> getMethod(msmFit, signature = c(object="lm", k="numeric", sw="logical", p="ANY", data="missing", family="missing")):


Method Definition:

function (object, k, sw, p, data, family, control) 
{
    if (!missing(data)) {
        if (is.list(data)) {
            if (class(data[[1]]) == "call") {
                call = data[[1]]
            }
            else {
                call = match.call()
            }
        }
        else {
            call = match.call()
        }
    }
    else {
        call = match.call()
    }
    if (missing(p)) 
        p = 0
    if (missing(control)) 
        control = list()
    control <- do.call(msmControl, control)
    if (p > 0) {
        var = object$model[, 1]
        Ar = apply(as.matrix(1:p), 1, function(el) {
            length(var) = length(var) - el
            var = c(rep(NA, el), var)
            return(var)
        })
        colnames(Ar) = paste(names(object$model)[1], "_", 1:p, 
            sep = "")
        aux = paste(colnames(Ar), collapse = "+")
        object = update(formula = as.formula(paste("~.+", aux, 
            sep = "")), data = data.frame(object$model, Ar), 
            object)
    }
    Coef = data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = k, ncol = length(coef(object))))
    std = rep(0, k)
    ind = sample(1:k, length(object$residuals), replace = T)
    for (i in 1:k) {
        data1 = as.data.frame(object$model[ind == i, , drop = F])
        mod1 = update(object, formula = object$terms, data = data1)
        Coef[i, ] = coef(mod1)
        std[i] = summary(mod1)$sigma
    }
    names(Coef) = names(coef(object))
    transMat = t(matrix(table(ind, c(ind[-1], NA))/rep(table(ind[-length(ind)]), 
        k), ncol = k))
    ans = new(Class = "MSM.lm", call = as.call(call), model = object, 
        k = k, switch = sw, p = p, Coef = Coef, std = std, transMat = transMat, 
        iniProb = rep(1/k, k))
    validMSM.linear(ans)
    validMSM.lm(ans)
    ans = em(ans, control)
    return(ans)
}
<environment: namespace:MSwM>

Signatures:
        object k         sw        p     data      family   
target  "lm"   "numeric" "logical" "ANY" "missing" "missing"
defined "lm"   "numeric" "logical" "ANY" "missing" "missing"
```

Comment: Look [here](https://github.com/cran/MSwM/blob/master/R/2MSM.r) and search for the string `.MSM.em`

Comment: Thanks very much! Is there perhaps a way to view this code in R, rather than on Github?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the conventional R stack, `git clone` the **MSwM** project to your own machine and look in the `R` subdirectory. It looks like `em` is a generic (I'm not an expert on the R object models!) which is why it has a funny extended name. You may be able to get away with looking directly at the `body()` of `.MSM.em`, but I'm not sure if it will be visible from your R session.

Please consider changing the tags for this question as the technical aims of the package (as opposed to the details of code structure!) aren't very relevant.